# How do i clear my cache on firefox

Tags: helpfile

I am trying to write and I have no idea how to I am a beginner and I'm not advanced THANK YOU. I tried using the terminal and entering the codes people suggested!

Comment: You should google it.

Comment: The terminal should have nothing to do with clearing browsing data. You don't need to be advanced to clear the cache in Firefox. Just follow the instructions here: https://kb.iu.edu/d/ahic

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are asking about **cache** or **cookies**

To clear **cache** :

Go to `preferences` >> `Advanced` >> `Network` >> `Cached webcontent`

there click on <kbd>clear now</kbd>

To clear cookies:

Go to preferences >> Privacy,

there you can clear cookies

Answer (score 0):

Just use Firefox itself. Click on the little three line menu button, click on preferences, and click on the privacy link that is on the left. Once you're there you can click on the option to delete all of your cache, some of you cache, cache from a certain time frame, etc. While you're there you can adjust the history settings if that is something you'd like to add as well.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's Chrome.

Comment: No? I just checked and did so in Firefox before typing it out. I just double checked and that's the process. This is the newest Firefox from the repository, not a beta or anything strange.

Comment: @Zacharee1 Firefox changed to the three-line button a while back

Comment: @CharlesGreen I see that now.

Comment: @KGIII The option to clear the cache is under preferences-> advanced

Comment: @Zacharee1 I think its part of "everybody look the same"

Comment: @Zacharee1I gave same answer!..

Comment: @CharlesGreen - That appears to be true, however it is also where I said it was on my Firefox install. This is a plain, unthemed, and stock Firefox. It's in the options, as a check box, right where I said it was. I can probably take a screen shot if needed but there are two locations to do this, at least on the stock, vanilla, Firefox from the repository. I only use Firefox long enough to download Opera so I've never changed it but keep it updated in case I do need it for something.